# With Guest Additions, VirtualBox Ubuntu slows to unusable speed

Tags: mount, virtualbox, 17.10, budgie

So, I've been trying and trying to get a good virtualbox of ubuntu x64 17.10 budgie running.  It's been a pain.  Basically every road block I run into involves dealing with guest additions.  If I install guest additions using the advised method of mounting the image and running `sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run install`, the system will slowly become unusable slow as described.  If I reboot, the system seems to be better, but certainly not as good as before running the aforementioned, and as stated it will just continue to slow down until it's practically unusable.

The greatest success I had was to just `sudo apt install virtualbox-*`.  This isn't ideal, but I got *almost* all the features up and running.  The one and most important feature I need from the package is shared folders.  Unfortunately, if I use this method, I can't for the life of me get shared folders to work, although everything else seems to operate fine.  I get the following.

```
addohm@budgie:~$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$(UID),gid=$(id -g) onedrive /media/host
[sudo] password for addohm: 
mount: /media/host: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on onedrive, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

This mounts fine under the first method.

I've read several posts regarding bad symbolic links in 5.1, but that ticket was closed as fixed.  I'm not sure what to do next.  Any advice?  What informations can I provide to help work this out?

Update:
Even after having "uninstalled" (`sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall`), the system continues to slow over time, even after having restored the snapshot I made before using the first method.  I have a second virtual machine, exact same setup, without ever having used the first method that responds as expected.

Update:

The VM slows without even being used; just running "idle".

Comment: I'm guessing here - host graphics driver issues?  What happens if you turn off the guest window animations via budgie-settings - style tab.

Comment: @fossfreedom why would one VM be affected, but not the other identical (sans guest additions source) VM?

Comment: No idea. But if the guest additions  is causing the issue then it is beginning to sound like a virtualbox issue.

Comment: @fossfreedom well, it didn't work.  Although I did end up putting together s working VM.  I'll post an answer, even though it's not a good one.

Comment: I have a VBox running Win7 VM with 4GB RAM, and a Lubuntu VM with 2GB RAM. When I fired up both, they both bogged down to a crawl, and eventually froze. I had to terminate Vbox to get control back.  Is it possible you have allocated too many resources to the machine that is bogging down?